# Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-parameters, routedata

I know, there are a method can be used for get current URL parameter base on route map,

```
Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

But I found when I run this method return System.NullReferenceException, so I checked in the all object got in the Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values, it is include two instance, which is `[Key:Controller, Value: Blog]` and `[key:action, Value:BlogCommit]`, then I check in my route map config file immediatelly, and think that is fine with

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

What is a default config, what is the wrong with my code?

From URL it is looks like:

http://www.example.com:1925/Blog/BlogPost/1

What is the root cause? Or is there any way to find out it?

Comment: though not that much of a problem. the url should point to action blogpost but you are saying that the action is blogcommit. is that ok?

Comment: Wow! you are right! i add one jquery.post() in javascrip, so even in the explorer show with above URL, but actually link to commit action, in that action not have id yet, so maybe that is the reason why i got error. let me have a try. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, hope it helps:**

```
string getParameterIdValue = (string)this.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

**Other options:**

```
string CurrentController = (string)this.RouteData.Values["controller"];
string CurrentAction = (string)this.RouteData.Values["action"];
```

**Got it here:**
https://forums.asp.net/t/1386372.aspx?Get+Route+Parameter+Value+in+Controller